# terraform try() function not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, try-catch, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to lookup an NLB's ENIs using a data lookup for the `aws_network_interfaces` terraform resource. This works like a charm if any ENIs can be found, but when you do your first plan and the AWS account is still empty the resource throws an error.

Here is the lookup:

```
data "aws_network_interfaces" "this" {

  filter {
    name   = "description"
    values = ["ELB net/${aws_lb.proxy.name}/*"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = ["${var.vpc_id}"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "status"
    values = ["in-use"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "attachment.status"
    values = ["attached"]
  }
}
```

To remedy this I want to use the terraform [try() function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html), but I get the following error:

[image]

This is how I implemented it:

```
locals {
  nlb_interface_ids = try(flatten(["${data.aws_network_interfaces.this.ids}"]), [])
}
```

I'm running terraform v0.12.18. Can someone please help.

Comment: This is not in direct answer to your question, but note that `try` can't be used for this situation anyway because the error you're looking to suppress is one coming from the `aws_network_interfaces` data source itself, not from the expression that's accessing an attribute from it. The data source is designed this way to remind you to apply whatever other Terraform configuration (or similar) is responsible for creating the network interface before applying this one.

Comment: I was hoping it would catch the error from the data resource, but you are correct, it does not. Do you know how to catch the error from the data resource?

Comment: There is no way to catch the error from the data resource. The intended usage model is that you create the network interface(s) you need first (either by running a different Terraform configuration, or by some other process) and only _then_ apply the Terraform configuration that depends on it. This error is there to force the correct ordering of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `try` function was added in version 0.12.20. You will need to update from 0.12.18 to at least that version to have access to the `try` function. Note the relevant [release notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.12/CHANGELOG.md#01220-january-22-2020) for this.